# Why do I get "undefined method `+@' for " is a credit: ":String (NoMethodError)" here?

Tags: ruby

I have some code that looks like this:

```
bal = sum_account_journal_entries(a)
if bal < 0
  puts a.name +' is a credit: ' + bal.to_s
else
  puts a.name +' is a debit: ' + bal.to_s
end
```

Here, `a` has method `name` which returns a `String`, and `bal` is a `Float`.

When I execute this code (it's part of a Cucumber step_definition, but that's not the source of this problem, as we'll soon see), I get:

```
undefined method `+@' for " is a credit: ":String (NoMethodError)
```

Which makes no sense.

Comment: Whitespace matters elsewhere too, `o.m(x, y)` versus `o.m (x, y)` for example.

Comment: Sure, but that's a situation where one reasonably expects it to matter (in that the latter isn't even obviously meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

The `+@` is **unary `+` operator**, which, in Ruby, is also a method that you can override. For example,

```
class One
  # Unary +
  def +@
    1
  end

  # Unary -
  def -@
    -1
  end
end

+One.new
=> 1

-One.new
=> -1
```

In your case, `a.name` is actually a method call (there's no public fields in ruby. Only public methods), so the Ruby virtual machine (YARV) compiles `a.name +' is a credit: '` (no space between `+` and the string) as

1. call `+@` on the string `' is a credit: '`
2. call method `name` on `a` with one argument: the result of step 1

Then when running the code, it will fail at step 1 and raises the error you saw.

On the other hand, `a.name + ' is a credit: '` (at least one space between `+` and the string), the interpreter interprets it as

1. call `a.name` with no argument
2. call `+` (binary `+` operator) on the result of step 1, with one argument `' is a credit: '`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there's at least one case where white space is important in Ruby. The following code executes as intended:

```
puts a.name + ' is a credit: ' + bal.to_s
```

which, when executed produces (for example):

```
Cash on Hand is a credit: -100.0
```

I look forward to any other answers which elucidate the *reason* this is so. I'll accept the best.

Comment: That's a consequence of allowing method calls without parentheses. Your original code is equivalent to: `puts(a.name(+' is a debit: ') + bal.to_s)`.

Comment: Your response ought to be an answer.